# Simulate ctrl+c press / send 'SIGINT' to child process

Tags: ruby, shell, concurrency, fork

What's wrong with this code? I am trying to send a `SIGINT` to the child process to allow `gst-launch-1.0` to exit gracefully once recording is done:

```rb
@pid = fork {
  exec("gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc rate-control=vbr bitrate=10000 quality-level=4 keyframe-period=30 num-slices=1 refs=1 max-bframes=2 ! queue ! mux. alsasrc ! audio/x-raw,width=16,depth=16,rate=44100,channel=1 ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location='/tmp/test-010.mp4' sync=false")
}
sleep 5
puts 'Killing child process and waiting...'
Process.kill 'INT', @pid
Process.wait
```

As you can see, I issue `Process.kill 'INT', @pid`, which, as far as I know, should be the same as pressing `ctrl+c` when running the `gst-launch-1.0` command (or any CLI command) directly.

But the output from the Ruby script is thus:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'vaapiencodeh264-0': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"\(GstVaapiDisplayGLX\)\ vaapidisplayglx0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock
Redistribute latency...
Killing child process and waiting...
```

And the script just hangs. Basically, it appears that the `Process.kill` call is not doing anything, or at least the signal isn't reaching the child process. What's wrong with my code?

For reference, here is what happens when I do run the `gst-launch-1.0` command directly from the CLI and press `ctrl+c` after a bit:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! vaapih264enc rate-control=vbr bitrate=10000 quality-level=4 keyframe-period=30 num-slices=1 refs=1 max-bframes=2 ! mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=test-006.mp4 sync=false
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'vaapiencodeh264-0': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"\(GstVaapiDisplayGLX\)\ vaapidisplayglx0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

And the capture is now in progress.

I press `ctrl+c` when I'm ready to end the capture, and the output looks like this:

```
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
EOS on shutdown enabled -- Forcing EOS on the pipeline
Waiting for EOS...
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
EOS received - stopping pipeline...
Execution ended after 0:00:08.524849001
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: `Ctrl+C` should be equivalent to a `SIGINT` kill of the foreground process group. I'd try `Process.kill 'INT', -@pgid`.

Comment: Does `kill -INT <pid>` work from bash?
Once you start it from the ruby script